# Mergesort with Vectors

Tags: vector, scheme, mergesort

I am trying to implement a mergesort algorithm in Scheme using vectors. I am aware of other sorting methods that I could use, but I would like to finish my code on this. What I have so far is as follows.

```
   (define (split v)
         (define (helper k v1 v2)
           (let ((m (floor (/ (vector-length v) 2))))
           (if (>= k m)
               (if (= k (vector-length v))
                   (cons v1 v2)
                   (helper (+ k 1) v1 (vector-append v2 (vector (vector-ref v k)))))
               (helper (+ k 1) (vector-append v1 (vector (vector-ref v k))) v2))))
         (helper 0 #() #()))

(define (merge v1 v2)
    (if (< (vector-ref v1 0) (vector-ref v2 0))
               (vector-append v1 v2)
               (vector-append v2 v1)))

(define (mergesort v)
  (if (<= (vector-length v) 1) 
      v
      (merge (mergesort (car (split v))) (mergesort (cdr (split v))))))
```

I am very close to my answer, but I am missing something. Any help here?

Comment: Nah, you don't "suck at coding". :-) It's just that vectors are very different from linked lists and the coding techniques for dealing with them are very different. Since vectors are seldom used in Scheme, there aren't many Scheme books and sites that give a decent treatment of vectors; they generally assume that, if you use them at all, you already know how to use them correctly.

Comment: I saw your comment in your subsequent question, and I get that you felt that I was condescending your coding. My answer was perhaps a little too directly worded, and for that I apologise. Direct feedback is a habit I have from the code reviews I do at work---at work, we have a policy where _every_ code checkin must be peer-reviewed, so everybody in our team has reviewed a lot of code, and over the years, I've developed a certain style for reviews. I'm sorry I treated your question as a code review when, in hindsight, that wasn't what you were seeking.

Comment: Thanks for this Chris; I removed the edit. I have seen some of your other forum posts, and I know that you are extremely good at what you do. I was just a little bit thrown by the fact that someone could solve the problem I was having in a matter of minutes when it took me an hour or two to put it together. I just need to practice more.

Comment: Now, it's my turn to make a confession. 1. My Scheme level is nowhere near the likes of Eli Barzilay, and I defer to him for the really hard stuff. :-) 2. I've been playing with Scheme since 2002, so I've had a lot of practice at this. I have every confidence that, in 11 years' time, you'll probably be way more experienced than me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main stumbling block for your implementation is that your `merge` function didn't correctly implement the merge algorithm. In the merge algorithm:

1. You have two pointers, which initially point to the start of the left-hand and right-hand lists.
2. If both pointers are at the end of their respective lists, you're done.
3. If either pointer is at the end of its respective list, output the remaining elements of the other list. Done.
4. At this point, both pointers point to an element. If the right-hand element is less than the left-hand element, output the right-hand element, and advance the right pointer. Otherwise, output the left-hand element, and advance the left pointer. Go to step 2.

My `merge-into!` function below implements such an approach.

Aside from that, the other main biggie is that your `split` function is trying to build vectors piecemeal, and sadly, that is a slow process: it has to copy all the elements into a new vector each time. It's not like `cons`! With vectors, don't be hesitant to use `vector-set!`; any immutable update of vectors is going to be slow and inefficient, so just bite the bullet and make it mutable. :-)

---

For reference, I wrote a new implementation from scratch (in Racket):

```
(define (split-halves vec)
  (vector-split-at vec (quotient (vector-length vec) 2)))

(define (merge lhs rhs)
  (define result (make-vector (+ (vector-length lhs)
                                 (vector-length rhs))))
  (merge-into! result lhs rhs))

(define (merge-into! result lhs rhs)
  (let loop ((i 0) (j 0) (k 0))
    (define (take-left)
      (vector-set! result k (vector-ref lhs i))
      (loop (add1 i) j (add1 k)))
    (define (take-right)
      (vector-set! result k (vector-ref rhs j))
      (loop i (add1 j) (add1 k)))
    (cond ((= k (vector-length result)) result)
          ((= i (vector-length lhs))
           (take-right))
          ((= j (vector-length rhs))
           (take-left))
          ((< (vector-ref rhs j) (vector-ref lhs i))
           (take-right))
          (else
           (take-left)))))

(define (mergesort vec)
  (case (vector-length vec)
    ((0 1) vec)
    (else (let-values (((lhs rhs) (split-halves vec)))
            (merge (mergesort lhs) (mergesort rhs))))))
```

The `merge-into!` function allows a mutating version of `mergesort` to be easily written:

```
(define (mergesort! vec)
  (case (vector-length vec)
    ((0 1) vec)
    (else (let-values (((lhs rhs) (split-halves vec)))
            (mergesort! lhs)
            (mergesort! rhs)
            (merge-into! vec lhs rhs)))))
```

---

If you don't use Racket, you may need these following additional definitions (which require [SRFI 43](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-43/srfi-43.html); see bottom of post if you don't have that):

```
(define (vector-split-at vec pos)
  (values (vector-copy vec 0 pos)
          (vector-copy vec pos (vector-length vec))))

(define (add1 x)
  (+ x 1))
```

`let-values` is defined in [SRFI 11](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-11/srfi-11.html). If you don't have that, here's a version of `mergesort` that uses `call-with-values`:

```
(define (mergesort vec)
  (case (vector-length vec)
    ((0 1) vec)
    (else (call-with-values (lambda () (split-halves vec))
                            (lambda (lhs rhs)
                              (merge (mergesort lhs) (mergesort rhs)))))))
```

`vector-copy` is defined in [SRFI 43](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-43/srfi-43.html). If you don't have that, here's a simplified version of that:

```
(define (vector-copy vec start end)
  (define result (make-vector (- end start)))
  (do ((i start (+ i 1))
       (j 0 (+ j 1)))
      ((>= i end) result)
    (vector-set! result j (vector-ref vec i))))
```